# How to make relation between 3 tables in laravel using laravel relation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-6.2

I have three tables:

```sql
SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `api_credentials`;
CREATE TABLE `api_credentials` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `api_provider_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `access` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `api_credentials_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
    KEY `api_credentials_api_provider_id_index` (`api_provider_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `api_credentials_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `api_credentials_api_provider_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`api_provider_id`) REFERENCES `api_providers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `api_providers`;
CREATE TABLE `api_providers` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `table_prefix` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- 2019-12-05 13:38:06
```

Here is my Model:
1. ApiCredential

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class ApiCredential extends Pivot
{

}
```

2. ApiProvider

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ApiProvider extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'table_prefix'
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->using('App\Models\ApiCredential');
    }
}
```

3. user model

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use App\Models\ApiProvider;
use App\Models\ApiCredential;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    public function apiProvider()
    {  
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ApiProvider','api_providers','user_id','api_provider_id');
    } 

    public function hasCredentials(String $apiProvider)
    {
        return $this->apiProvider()->where('name', $apiProvider)->get();
    } 
}
```

**Now What I want:**
I want to get record from `api_credentials` table based on `user` and `api_provider`. Let say if I have three records in `api_providers` (names are adscane, cpalead, offertorro).

I am running this function to get api_credential of `cpalead`.

```php
User::find(1)->hasCredentials('cpalead');
```

But it is not giving an expected result.

Can someone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Shoudn't the User class's `apiProvider()` function be using `api_credentials` instead of `api_providers` as its pivot table?

Comment: Or even using the custom pivot model like in ApiProvider class's `user()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```php
# User model
public function apiProvider()
{  
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ApiProvider','api_providers','user_id','api_provider_id');
}
```

Should be

```php
# User model
public function apiProvider()
{  
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ApiProvider','api_credentials','user_id','api_provider_id');
}
```

**EDIT** Accessing the api_credentials:

2. Using a `hasMany` relationship

```php
# User model
public function apiCredentials()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ApiCredential')
}
```

```php
# ApiProvider model
public function apiCredentials()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ApiCredential');
}
```

```php
# ApiCredential model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}

public function apiProvider()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ApiProvider');
}
```

And then, we redefine the `hasCredentials()` function to work as follows:

```php
# User model
public function hasCredentials(String $apiProvider)
{
    $this->apiCredentials()->whereHas('apiProvider', function ($query) use ($apiProvider) {
         $query->where('name', '=', $apiProvider);
    })
    ->get();
}
```

Using the data would look like this:

```php
$user = User::find($id);

foreach($user->hasCredentials('api_provider_name') as $apiCredential)
{
    // $apiCredential->name
    // $apiCredential->table_prefix
}
```

Comment: First option is working but it returning records from api_credential table while I want matched record from api_credentials table.

Comment: What you want is either accessing the pivot which can be done on a record to record basis or through a second relationship. I'll edit these options in my answer.

Comment: I just want info from api_creentias based on user and api_provider_name

Comment: I edited my answer. I believe defining and using a hasMany relationship may be the best way for you.

Comment: thanks second solution `Using a hasMany relationship` solved my query..

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
namespace App\Model;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ApiCredential extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function apiProvider()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ApiProvider::class);
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace App\Model;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ApiProvider extends Model
{

    public function ApiCredentials()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ApiCredential::class);
    }

}
```

and

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    public function ApiCredentials()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ApiCredential::class);
    }

}
```

now query like this

```
    User::with('apiCredentials.apiProvider',)
        ->where('id',1)
        ->whereHas('apiCredentials.apiProvider', function ($query)  {
        $query->where('name','cpalead' );
    })->get();
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it is not working. The solution provided by @IGP is working perfectly.